# Finite generation and profinite completion

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a (countable) residually finite group whose profinite completion is topologically finitely generated. Must $G$ be finitely generated?

Comment: Wouldn't $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ be a counterexample? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DonuArapura my fault. Edited.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ still a counterexample?

Comment: @DonuArapura: yes it works (that subgroups of finite index in $\hat{\mathbf{Z}}$ can be checked by hand without any fancy theorem. By Nikolov-Segal (and Serre in the pro-$p$-case), any infinite topologically finitely generated profinite group also works. Of course it provides no countable example, but very simple countable examples have been pointed out as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Take $G=\oplus_{p} C_p$, where the sum is over all primes $p$ and $C_p$ is the cyclic groups of order $p$. Then $G$ is clearly locally finite and infinite and therefore not finitely generated. However, it is easy to see that the profinite completion of $G$ is $\Pi_p C_p$ which is a cyclic profinite group.